# Get laravel mix to use a specific .env file

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

With laravel mix I can specify a `.env` to include some variables into my project.

Is it possible to make mix use my file `.env.development` when `NODE_ENV=development`? Right now, mix just keeps grabbing the `.env` file and ignoring the `.env.development` file.

Is it possible to somehow configure this?

My current `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "rmdist": "rimraf dist"
  },
  ...
```

My current `webpack.mix.js`:

```
  let mix = require('laravel-mix');
  mix.setPublicPath('dist')
     .js('src/app.js', 'scripts/')
     .extract([
        'jquery',
        'axios',
        'babel-polyfill',
        'lodash',
        'tether',
        'vue',
        'bootstrap-vue',
        'vuex',
        'vuex-localstorage'
     ])
     .sass('src/styles/app.scss', 'styles/')
     .copyDirectory('src/assets', 'dist/assets')
     .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        uglify: true
      })
     .version();

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
     mix.sourceMaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `dotenv` node package to read the `.env` file. It's read through `process.env.<KEY-NAME>`.

I'm unsure if **[Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix)** has it already in the background *(I think it so)*. Yet, it never hurts to simply run this first:

```
yarn add dotenv
# or 
npm i dotenv
```

---

In your webpack file, you can use it like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
// .. (at the top)
// ..
require('dotenv').config();

const isProduction = process.env.APP_ENV === 'production';
```

---

The **[PHP Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)** package and **[Node Dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)** package read from the same file.